# How to get the id of the selected item of the Autocompletetextview in android?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-volley, autocompletetextview

My question is when i select the state from the autocompletetextview it always return 1 as an id. but i want to get the id accordingly to the state as per shown my json. Example (StateName = Assam then StateId = 4).but i am always getting id as 1. i am using model class to set the id and get from it.but there is no change i am getting the id as a 1. If anyone know how can i resolve this problem.then please tell me. thanks in advance.

```
This is my jsonResponce :-   

 {
      "ReplyCode": 1,
      "Message": "Franchisee and Plans List",

     "data2": [
        {
          "StateId": 1,
          "StateName": "Andaman and Nicobar Island",
          "CountryId": 1
        },
        {
          "StateId": 2,
          "StateName": "Andhra Pradesh",
          "CountryId": 1
        },
        {
          "StateId": 3,
          "StateName": "Arunachal Pradesh",
          "CountryId": 1
        },
        {
          "StateId": 4,
          "StateName": "Assam",
          "CountryId": 1
        },
```

This is the method by which i am getting the data from the json :-

```
public void volleyStatedata() {

        if (mGeneralUtilities.isConnected()) {
            mProgressDialog.show();
            StringRequest stateRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, GlobalData.REGISTER_DATA_URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {


                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data2");
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    PojoState pojoState = new PojoState();
                                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String stateId = jsonObject1.getString("StateId");
                                    String stateName = jsonObject1.getString("StateName");
                                    mStateList.add(stateName);
                                    mStateIdList.add(stateId);
                                    pojoState.setmStateList(mStateList);
                                    pojoState.setmStateId(stateId);
                                    mpojoStateList.add(pojoState);



                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                            Log.e("error", "" + volleyError.getMessage());


                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


                    return params;
                }
            };

            RequestQueue stateQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

            stateQueue.add(stateRequest);
        } else {

            mGeneralUtilities.showAlertDialog("Hey User !", "Please connect to the internet", "Ok");

        }
    }
```

And this is my adapter where i am applying onItemclick listner on the autocompltetextview :-

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> mStateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStateList);
        mActState.setAdapter(mStateAdapter);
        mActState.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                mpojoStateList.get(i).getmStateId();


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses `i` that returns in the `onItemClick` callback, which refers to the item you clicked from the visible items in the auto-complete list, not your original list. When you click on the first item in the auto-complete list, `i=0`, which means it always returns the "*Andaman and Nicobar Island*" item whose `StateId=1`.

Off the top of my head, you can get the item String from the `mStateAdapter` and compare it to your `mpojoStateList` and find the corresponding item. (Check the sample code)

```
    final ArrayAdapter<String> mStateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStateList);
    mActState.setAdapter(mStateAdapter);
    mActState.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            String itemName = mStateAdapter.getItem(i);

            for (PojoState pojo : mpojoStateList) {
                if (pojo.mStateName.equals(itemName)) {
                    String id = pojo.getmStateId(); // This is the correct ID
                    break; // No need to keep looping once you found it.
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

It also is better if, inside your `PojoState` object, you override your `toString()` method and make it return the `mStateName`, and pass the `mpojoStateList` to the adapter without having to make 3 `ArrayLists`. That way, `mStateAdapter.getItem(i)` will return a `PojoState` object instead of a String, and you can use its ID without referring to the returned position (`i`).

Comment: if list has two same name available then it not working